# How can I fix this MySql Exception? [c#]

Tags: c#, mysql

So I tried to create a simple login form wich uses a MySql database.
I made a simple MySql database at hostinger and a table named users with two columns a username column and a password column. Then I coded this:

```
namespace MySql_Login_Form
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=mysql.hostinger.nl;Database=u725015652_users;User Id=u725015652_gewoo;Password=[MyPassword];");
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '" + usernameTxt.Text + "' AND `password` = '" + passwordTxt.Text + "'", connection);
                adapter.Fill(table);

                if (table.Rows.Count >= 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Succeed");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("False");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My database details:
[image]

When I run the code I get this error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Host is unknown
   at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.CreateStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings, Boolean unix)
   at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at MySql_Login_Form.Form1.loginBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\.....\Login Form\MySql Login Form\Form1.cs:Line 28
```

Line 28 is this line:

```
adapter.Fill(table);
```

Comment: Your code cannot connect to mysql because the mysql host name is not recognised.

Comment: The error is in this: _Host is onbekend_, which means 'Host is unknown'. Verify that you can reach the host and optionally provide a port number if applicable.

Comment: Also that is a horrible way to do you sql command ... look up sql injection

Comment: Probably remote connection to your database is disabled and you run the code locally

Comment: If you search in their Frequently Asked Question (or Knowldge base) you will find that the remote connection to their hosted mysql servers are disabled for security reasons (at least on the free service option) Only PHP scripts running on their servers are able to reach the mysql db.

Comment: @Steve Alright that explains a lot, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to MySql server.
Most likely need to provide a port number
*Server=mysql.hostinger.nl:**12345***

I kinda wonder if you actually have a DNS entry for *mysql.hostinger.nl* as well. If not, you either need a DNS entry for that or just use IP address instead.

Besides, your code is vulnerable to Sql Injection.

```
adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '" + usernameTxt.Text + "' AND `password` = '" + passwordTxt.Text + "'", connection);
```

Even if security is of no concern, I'd advise you to fix it.